# Can't access accordion in IFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dotnetnuke, accordion

I am using the accordion from jQuery together with DotNetNuke.
Now the DNN page is loaded into an IFrame dynamicly, so the Page_load event of the page which includes the IFrame, the IFrame is not filled yet.

```
<div class="dvFrame">
            <iframe class="IFrame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" runat="server" id="frmDNN" ></iframe>
</div>
```

In the page_load:

```
frmDNN.Attributes.Add("src", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dnn"] + request);
```

The accordion that is loaded into the IFrame:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <div>
      <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    </div>
    <div>
       <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
       <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now with some Javascript I should be able to say that the div should act like an accordion.
But with every attempt, I seem to fail.

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
```

Can someone help me with this problem, it would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about DotNetNuke, but I think if you're defining the Accordion javascript in the main page and the accordion HTML in the iFrame you may need to change the javascript to:

```
window.frmDNN.$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });
```